# Android App : Should I use the MEAN stack or the default android studio available

Tags: android, mean-stack

I am new to android programming and considering building my first app. 
On doing some primary design research, got to know the popular MEAN stack for application building. 
However, the android developer website, particularly this URL :-
http://developer.android.com/tools/workflow/index.html
does not mention anything related to MEAN stack.

What approach should I take ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> got to know the popular MEAN stack for application building

I am not aware of anything named "MEAN" with respect to native Android app development.

The [mean-stack](/questions/tagged/mean-stack) description says that MEAN is "a methodology that employs MongoDB, Express, AngularJS and Node.js to provide a complete end-to-end system". In that case, while some of that might be used server-side, a regular Android application cannot be MEAN, as a regular Android application is not a Web app and therefore would not use AngularJS.

You could create a MEAN application and use a `WebView` to wrap that in a native Android app. You won't see much written about that in Android developer documentation, as wrap-a-Web-site-in-an-app is not the sort of thing that such documentation focuses on.

> What approach should I take ?

If you want to write a Web app, you could certainly use MEAN if you wanted.

If you want to write a regular native Android app, you will not use most of MEAN.

Answer (score 1):

MEAN stack has both the server side and client side. Most probably you won't have server on your android app. If you just want your android app holding your client side only.

You can convert it the hybrid way(Often known as HTML5 App). You can use Phonegap or Cordova.

Here are the links:

- [Phonegap](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiEy8ToqrjQAhXEPo8KHSC9BgwQFggfMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphonegap.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNG1ra7Js9Qo6QGHtSOloIx4qGEnOA&sig2=ddLxzGGpuHfohJY98TjBkw)
- [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/)